# Why is a const view not a range?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

If I create a view, then it's a range.  That seems reasonable.

However, if it's const, then it becomes a non-range:

```
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    int values[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    auto odd_values = values | std::views::filter([](int i){ return i % 2; });
    static_assert(std::ranges::range<decltype(odd_values)>);

    auto const odd_ref = odd_values;    
    static_assert(!std::ranges::range<decltype(odd_ref)>); // WHY NOT?
}
```

This is surprising - I don't see any reason I shouldn't be able to read the contents, just as I could from, say a `const std::vector`.

In case it's an implementation bug, I experienced this with GCC 11, using `-std=c++20`; library is libstdc++-11.

---

If I add a call to `std::ranges::begin()` I get plenty of diagnostics, showing it not finding a member function nor anything via ADL, then running up against the backstop deleted function that's there to prevent `std::begin` matching.

From the error messages, it seems that we're lacking const versions of `begin()` and `end()` member functions from the view class.  Is that expected, or have they just been missed out?

That led me to a simpler failing example:

```
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    int values[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    auto const odd_values = values | std::views::filter([](int i){ return i % 2; });

    odd_values.begin();  // ERROR HERE
}
```

```
view.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
view.cpp:9:21: error: passing ‘const std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<int [3]>, main()::<lambda(int)> >’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
    9 |     odd_values.begin();  // ERROR HERE
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from view.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11/ranges:1452:7: note:   in call to ‘constexpr std::ranges::filter_view<_Vp, _Pred>::_Iterator std::ranges::filter_view<_Vp, _Pred>::begin() [with _Vp = std::ranges::ref_view<int [3]>; _Pred = main()::<lambda(int)>]’
 1452 |       begin()
      |       ^~~~~
```

So why doesn't the view have const versions of `begin()` and `end()`?

Comment: FWIW, compiles clean in vs2022 with /stdc++latest

Comment: @pm100, does latest start implementing some changes from c++23 drafts which change the behaviour? Or does it also compile in C++20?

Comment: doesnt even recognize `std::views` in c++20

Comment: @pm100 Yes. The question is: _why_ does it compile clean? OP is asserting that `odd_ref` is _NOT_ a range, and the question is why not?

Comment: @Barry - I have no idea - hence the 'FWIW in my comment. I dont even know what these things (ranges, views etc) do although I will go look now

Comment: @pm100 That's what I'm trying to explain: the fact that it compiles clean _is the question_: why does it compile clean, when OP expected it not to?

Comment: Thanks @康桓瑋 for finding the duplicate - I did look hard, I promise.

Comment: @pm100 - just to clarify (I didn't read carefully enough yesterday) - are you saying that `std::ranges::begin(odd_ref)` compiles cleanly on your platform?  Or that `std::ranges::range<decltype(odd_ref)>`is false, as shown here? If the former, it seems that that the linked question explains one approach to achieving the complexity requirements in a thread-safe way, and it might be worth you adding a comment over on that question.

Comment: @TobySpeight Note that *not* all range adaptors have this time complexity requirement, most range adaptors are indeed const-iterable if specific constraints are satisfied. I've added a new answer below the origin.